# How to print out multiple statement within a conditional to the r console?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

In my R script I print different variables and functions. The script is getting a bit more complex so I started to enclose the code in conditions. So far so good but now in the console prints out only the last variable or function within the condition. It looks like in R a condition is working somehow as a function that only returns the value of the last statement. In the following example only «b» is printed out but I expected to see «a» and «b».

```
somevariable <- TRUE

if (somevariable) {
  a <- 'a‘;
  a
  b <- 'b‘;
  b
}
```

Is there a way to print both including the statement itself so that the ouput looks like

```
> a <- 'a';
>   a
[1] "a"
>   b <- 'b';
>   b
[1] "b"
```

Comment: specify `return(list(a,b))` at the very end, and remove `a` and `b` part, is that it? It's not clear if you want to just return multiple values or print them to the console once you call a function.

Comment: If you want to print both 'a' and 'b', use `print(a)` and `print(b)` explicitly, else R returns/prints the last executable statement within the brackets `{}`

Comment: Thanks, only use `print(a)` and `print(b)` would be an option if I only need the results. But what I have in mind to print the result including the statement itself so you can clearly see the which output is coming from which statement.